# How to echo from web to a file in windows terminal?

Tags: terminal, git, echo

What I want is to run a command in a terminal that will download a [Visual Studio git ignore raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/VisualStudio.gitignore), save it to `.gitignore` file in a folder where my terminal is opened on my Windows 10 machine.

I've already tried:

```
echo >> .gitignore 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/VisualStudio.gitignore'
echo >> .gitignore https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/VisualStudio.gitignore
```

Comment: It's considered good practice to put your solution in an answer instead of putting it in your question.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/VisualStudio.gitignore > .gitignore
```

Kind regards